# Change custom class value in range based for loop

Tags: c++, for-loop, set

I'm building a data structure to keep track of count and rank of elements. I have a set of a struct I made and when I'm trying to modify the members in the struct with the range based for loop I get this error:

*error: cannot assign to variable 'it' with const-qualified type 'const item &'*

I already overloaded the < operator. What do I have to do more to make this work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

struct item {
        int val, count;

        item(int v, int c) : val{v}, count{c} {}
};

bool operator<(const item &a, const item &b) {
            return a.val < b.val;
}


class DS {

    set<item> S;

    public:
    void notWorking(int x) {
            for (auto &it : S) {
                    if (it.val < x) it.count++;
            }   
    }   
};


int main() {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You probably want `map<int, int>`instead.

Comment: oh great thanks! I didn't find this when I searched

Comment: Or see the linked question for another possibility.